# How to take exponent of a column and add column to existing file using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have file1 as below

```
log10_BF
-1
-2
-3
-4
```

I want to create a second file that has a second column which adds a header BF and shows the corresponding antilog value for each line to show this

```
log10_BF BF
-1      0.1
-2      0.01
-3      0.001
-4      0.0001
```

So far I have been able to add the new header

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{$0=$0" BF";} file1
```

I'm not sure how to go about getting the antilog value based on the values in column 1.

Comment: I'm curious - what do you think `-F,` does?

Comment: I believe it is used to specify a field separator and now see how it would be unnecessary here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {print $0, "BF"} NR!=1 {print $1, 10**$1}' file1
log10_BF BF
-1 0.1
-2 0.01
-3 0.001
-4 0.0001
```

Not much to explain.